# Remove white box overlaying PGAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm using PGAdmin4, and ever since updating to version 4.10 I've had a random white box on the screen.

I've discovered that I can minimise this box, but there doesn't seem to be any way to close it.

How can I remove this rather annoying thing?!

[image]